# Variation of Euler's theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I think the following works, but am not sure how to prove it. I tested it up to $n = 1000000$. It's related to Euler's theorem.

Given $n$, a multiple of 3, s.t. $\gcd(n, 10) = 1$, is it true that:

$$10 ^ {\varphi(3 n) / 2} \equiv 1 \pmod{9 n}$$

Here $\varphi$ is Euler's totient function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's true. Try writing $n = 3^k m$ where $\gcd(3, m) = 1$ so you can write

$$\frac{\varphi(3n)}{2} = \frac{\varphi(3^{k+1}) \varphi(m)}{2} = 3^k \varphi(m)$$

and then use the Chinese remainder theorem to work $\bmod 3^{k+2}$ and $\bmod m$ separately. The $\bmod m$ part is immediate so only the $\bmod 3^{k+2}$ part presents difficulties, and for that part you'll want to take advantage of the fact that $10 \equiv 1 \bmod 9$. You may want to look up a result called [Lifting the Exponent](https://brilliant.org/wiki/lifting-the-exponent/) (LTE for short), but you can try proving the result you need by induction on $k$ first.